# Will my this implementation of binary search always work correctly?

Tags: algorithm, scala, sorting, binary-search

I've written code for binary searching an array of integers in scala, which is shown below. I know binary search is quite tricky to implement. So, I want to know if this code would always work correctly. I have tried it by testing it against a test array, and it works. However, I'm not sure if it would always work.

**NOTE:** Assume that the array size is never more than half of the maximum integer value.

```
def binarySearch(arr: Array[Int], starti: Int, endi: Int, x: Int) : Int =
{
    if (starti > endi)
        return -1

    val guess = (starti + endi) / 2

    if (arr(guess) == x)
        return guess

    if ((guess != 0) && (arr(guess-1) == x))
        return guess - 1

    if ((guess != endi) && (arr(guess+1) == x))
        return guess + 1

    if (arr(guess) > x)
        return binarySearch(arr, starti, guess-1, x)
    else
        return binarySearch(arr, guess+1, endi, x) 
}
```

Comment: It contains the classic overflowing addition for the midpoint calculation, it can go negative, the division by 2 leaves it negative (a logical shift would work correctly) and then you have a negative index.

Comment: How can division by 2 of positive numbers produce negative number? Assuming that the array size is no more than the maximum integer value.

Comment: Division by 2 doesn't produce the negative number, the addition does. The division just leaves it negative, while it could have been salvaged by treating the result of the addition as unsigned.

Comment: I see, but that would still require a very big array. Something as big as half of the maximum integer value. Right?

Comment: Right, but you can have those, right? You can in Java

Comment: Yes of course. But the program I would be using it on, don't have such big arrays. They could be of size millions, but not billion.

Answer (score 2):

Under your assumptions it *seems* to be correct. However, I'd always recommend writing `val guess = starti + (endi - starti) / 2` instead of `val guess = (starti + endi) / 2`, since the latter can overflow in the general case (but not under your assumption).

Furthermore, searching the neighbors is fairly uncommon and in your case its just overhead, since you use `return binarySearch(arr, starti, guess-1, x)` instead of `return binarySearch(arr, starti, guess-2, x)` and similarly for `return binarySearch(arr, guess+1, endi, x)`, ignoring that you already checked these.

I'd recommend to remove the tests for the neighbors of `guess`. Instead, calculate the size of the interval (`endi - starti`) and if it is smaller than some threshold, linearly search the array for `x` (linear traversals are quite fast due to how caches work). If it's larger, use recursive binary search. Note that in the following example I slightly changed the interface: the given search interval does not include `endi` to make the initial call more comfortable (`binarySearch(arr, 0, arr.length, x)`).

```
def binarySearch(arr: Array[Int], starti: Int, endi: Int, x: Int) : Int =
{
    val threshold = 100

    val len = endi - starti
    if (len <= 0) {
        return -1
    }

    // Optional and purely for performance reasons
    if (len < threshold) {
        for (i <- starti until endi) {
            if (arr(i) == x) {
                return i
            }
        }
    }


    val guess = starti + len / 2
    if (arr(guess) == x) {
        return guess
    } else if (arr(guess) > x) {
        return binarySearch(arr, starti, guess, x)
    } else {
        return binarySearch(arr, guess + 1, endi, x)
    }
}
```

Note that the threshold value just a random guess and has to be determined by doing performance measurements.

Comment: I added the case for returning -1 when x is not found. See the first line in the function. Also, my assumption is that the array size is never more than the half of maximum value of an integer.

Comment: @hk6279. Are you asking about my code? If that is so, it will search it fine, that is, it will return 0.

Comment: It will return 0, as this is the first index (just tested). Be aware that the interface of my version slightly differs from the original one. In the original one, the interval contained `endi`, in my version, it is excluded. IMHO this makes initial invocation more elegant, as you can use `binarySearch(arr, 0, arr.length, x)` but is just personal preference.